# Can't load static files in Django with right setting

Tags: django, static

Can't load static files from app called 'gameMuster' even if I'm sure everything is okey with settings.py.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzKLq.png)

[Statics confs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2uob.png)

[Installed apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giXr0.png)

Comment: Please replace links to and screenshots of code with code itself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I don't kno, but try this

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gameMuster/static')
]
```

Comment: Still the same cause actually join function returns same path both in my situation and in yours.

Comment: maybe collect static?